# get all tags using specific style by BeautifulSoup in python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to parse some HTML files. I want to extract all text using a specific font size. For instance, I want to get all text of `p`, `div`, `span`, etc tags using `font-size:10px` in their style. I am using BeautifulSoup to parse my HTML files and extract the preferred data. To extract data of tags using specific font sizes, I used the following script in python. While it does not work.

```
file = open("file.html", "r")
soup = BeautifulSoup(file.read(), features="html.parser")
main_texts = soup.findAll(attrs={"style":"font-size:10px"})
for item in main_texts :
   whole_text += item.getText()
```

Also, My HTML content is like this

```
<span style="font-family: TimesNewRomanPSMT; font-size:10px">   </span><span style="font-family: ABCDEE+Calibri-Bold; font-size:11px"> </span><span style="font-family: TimesNewRomanPSMT; font-size:14px">Academic Qualifications <span style="position:absolute; border: black 1px solid; left:36px; top:143px; width:159px; height:0px;"></span>
</span><span style="font-family: TimesNewRomanPSMT; font-size:10px">2012-Current  CPA (Australia)    CPA (Aust.) Holder </span><span style="font-family: TimesNewRomanPSMT; font-size:14px"> </span><span style="font-family: TimesNewRomanPSMT; font-size:10px">2010-2012  Royal Melbourne Institute of Technology     Bachelor in Business (Accountancy)       2006-2009         Ngee Ann Polytechnic                            Diploma in Accountancy  2002-2005        Henderson Secondary School                           GCE ‘O’ Levels  1996-2001        River Valley Primary School </span><span style="font-family: TimesNewRomanPSMT; font-size:10px">                            PSLE </span><span style="font-family: ABCDEE+Calibri; font-size:15px">  Co-Curriculum Achievements <span style="position:absolute; border: black 1px solid; left:36px; top:399px; width:189px; height:1px;"></span>
</span><span style="font-family: TimesNewRomanPSMT; font-size:10px">NPCC (2002 -2005)     -National Youth Achievement Award (Bronze)       -CCA Merit Award (NPCC)  Ngee Ann Poly (2006 – 2009)   -Freshmen Orientation Sub-Committee Member       -Freshmen Recruitment Sub-Committee Member       -Ngee Ann Canoeing Club Member </span><span style="font-family: ABCDEE+Cambria; font-size:12px"> Nippon Yusen Kaisha (2011- 2012) - Social Recreational Committee Member </span><span style="font-family: ABCDEE+Calibri; font-size:15px"> Personal Skills <span style="position:absolute; border: black 1px solid; left:36px; top:549px; width:91px; height:1px;"></span>
</span><span style="font-family: TimesNewRomanPS-BoldMT; font-size:10px">Software Skills </span><span style="font-family: TimesNewRomanPSMT; font-size:10px">1.</span><span style="font-family: ArialMT; font-size:11px"> </span><span style="font-family: TimesNewRomanPSMT; font-size:10px">Microsoft Office (Excel, Pivot, V-lookup, Powerpoint) Excellent </span><span style="font-family: TimesNewRomanPSMT; font-size:10px">2.</span><span style="font-family: ArialMT; font-size:11px"> </span><span style="font-family: TimesNewRomanPSMT; font-size:10px">Bloomberg       Intermediate </span><span style="font-family: TimesNewRomanPSMT; font-size:10px">3.</span><span style="font-family: ArialMT; font-size:11px"> </span><span style="font-family: TimesNewRomanPSMT; font-size:10px">Thomson Reuters      Intermediate 4.</span>
```

Do you have any idea to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an [`[attribute*="value"]`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) CSS Selector.

To use a CSS Selector, instead of the `.find_all()` method, use [`.select()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
...
# The following will select all `style` elements containing `font-size:10px`
main_text = soup.select('[style*="font-size:10px"]')
```